# variable in scp filename not working?

Tags: bash, scp

I'm trying to scp a backup tgz file from one server to another every night. The backup script uses the following $date var just fine but when I modify it slightly for scp it breaks:

```
#!/bin/sh
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
rbfile=`/backups/$date_00h00.tgz`
scp $rbfile user@myserverip:
```

But the script dies with the error:

```
/backups/.tgz: No such file or directory
```

On a side note, I really should switch to rsync for better remote backups - the tgz files are at 3.5GB now. Any recommended tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when using `$date_00h00` you tell bash to use the variable named `date_00h00`, because letters, numbers and _ characters are allowed as variables names.

Enclose the variable name in {} and it will correct the problem :

```
rbfile=`/backups/${date}_00h00.tgz`
```